# Mac mini hangs onssh, until VNC connects

Tags: ssh, vnc

I have a bit of a weird problem with my new mac mini

I tried logging in via ssh today, but it just hangs before password promt.
I thought that it was weird, because i have made it possible to ssh to the machine. I then logged in with VNC but couldn't find anything wrong. I then tried loggin in with ssh again, and it logged in with no trouble at all. what could cause this problem, and how do i fix it. I would like it so i can just ssh to the machine without going through VNC first.

many thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the logs to such a session to the question. Both client-side (`ssh -vvv` output) and server-side logs (created by way of an `sshd_config` option) would be useful. Without such logs, it's impossible to debug something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that it was because the server was set to sleep on inactivity, so I couldn't connect via ssh because it was sleeping, but at the time when I connected via, VNC the server had woken from LAN connection.

all in all, a stupid mistake